# Solr fields mapping?

Tags: solr

I am indexing documents into solr from a source. At source, for each document, i have some associated properties which i am indexing & fetching into solr.

What i am doing is i am mapping some fields from source properties with solr schema fields. But i could see couple of extra fields in solr logs which i am not mapping. While querying in solr admin UI, i could see only mapped fields.

E.g. In below logs, i am using only content_name & content content_modifier but i could see Template fields also.

> INFO  - 2014-09-18 12:07:47.185; org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor; [collection1] webapp=/solr path=/update/extract params={literal.content_name=1_.000&literal.content_modifier=System&literal.Template={8ad4d8f0-93a7-4941-9657-cf3706f00409} {add=[1_.000 (1479581071766978560)]} 0 0

So whats happening here? Will solr index only mapped fields and skip rest of unmapped ones? Or will solr index all fields including mapped & non-mapped but on admin UI , it will show only mapped fields?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is defined by what your solrconfig and schema say because you can configure it any way you want. Here is how it works for the example schema for Solr 4.10:

1) In solrconfig.xml, [the handler use "uprefix" parameter](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_10_0/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml#L1104) to map all fields NOT in schema to a dynamic field **ignored_***

2) In schema.xml, that dynamic field [has type **ignored**](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_10_0/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml#L233)

3) [Type **ignored** (in the same file)](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/lucene_solr_4_10_0/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/schema.xml#L705) is defined as **stored=false** and **indexed=false**. Which means do not complain if you get one of fields with matching pattern, but do nothing with, literally ignore.

So, if you don't like that, you can modify any part of that pipeline. The easiest test would be to change the dynamic field to use type string and reindex. Then, you should see the rest of the fields.